# Weird behavior with long ints in pandas iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

```
    d = {'2014-07-10 08:26:29.091199': {'Col':'12976482066142964'}, '2014-07-10 08:26:29.171198': {'Col': '129764923110142964'}, '2014-07-10 08:30:46.906344': {'Col': np.nan}}
```

Then get it into a DataFrame

```
x=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')
```

Now if I iterate over this it works perfectly:

```
In [384]: for idx, row in x.iterrows():
    print row['Col']
   .....:
12976482066142964
129764923110142964
nan
```

Now lets save it as a csv:

```
 x.to_csv('x')
```

Load it:

```
xs = pd.read_csv('x')
```

Now I want to check the first value of both:

```
In [389]: xs['Col'].ix[0]
Out[389]: 12976482066142964.0

In [390]: x['Col'].ix[0]
Out[390]: '12976482066142964'
```

Looks like the save caused the column to switch to a float. That's not what I want, but not back breaking. I can work around it. Unfortunately, if I now try to iterate over the df I loaded from csv:

```
In [391]: for idx, row in xs.iterrows():
    print row['Col']
   .....:
1.29764820661e+16
1.2976492311e+17
nan
```

Seems like a bug?

Version:

```
In [116]: pd.__version__
Out[116]: '0.14.0'
```

Comment: Your nan is causing the issue

Comment: @PadraicCunningham how is the OP's grandmother involved in this? Sorry couldn't resist ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numbers are not representable exactly by `float64` and you have a nan, so you are stuck with `object` dtype. You must specify this (its a pseudo bug in that pandas *could* figure it out, but would need someone to debug it, but I think their might be an unreasonable perf hit so not high on the list)

```
In [16]: pd.read_csv('test.csv',index_col=0,dtype={'Col' : object})
Out[16]: 
                                           Col
2014-07-10 08:26:29.091199   12976482066142964
2014-07-10 08:26:29.171198  129764923110142964
2014-07-10 08:30:46.906344                 NaN

In [17]: pd.read_csv('test.csv',index_col=0,dtype={'Col' : object}).dtypes
Out[17]: 
Col    object
dtype: object
```

See [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5697) for the issue